# Careers invitation never arrived

Tags: support, jobs, email

A colleague of mine tried to send me an invitation to *Careers 2.0* today, but received the following error message:

> *Sorry, that email has already been sent an invitation.*

I never received an invitation, or perhaps caught by a spam filter. Is it possible to recover it or force the new one to be sent?

Comment: A sub question would be why a check against resending an invite is even necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no problem. I can force the system to send out a new one. Check your e-mail!

Comment: Thanks Juice, I received it!

Comment: Brute force always work! :-)